# How do I serve static files and dynamic files in Django 1.3 development urls?

Tags: django, django-urls, django-static

I'm a little stumped. In development, I'm trying to serve both static AND dynamic files for my app in DJango 1.3. I love the new static features, but I can't seem to get this to work properly.

When I read the docs, it looks like the following should work. It serves dynamic stuff fine, but not static.

```
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        url(r'^media/dynamic/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
            'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
        }),
   )
```

Comment: Just to clarify. This does work. The problem was that I had manually set the STATIC_URL in settings which is what was causing the problem.

Comment: add an answer to the question to that effect and accept it.

Comment: I tried to earlier and it wouldn't let me. Doing so now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In django 1.3 static and dynamic content have been separated. to use the new features, set up your project like this:

```
project
 |- app1
 |- media       # exists only on server/folder for dynamic content
 |- static-root # exists only on server/folder for static content
 |- static      # folder for site-specific static content
 |- settings.py
 |- manage.py
 `- urls.py
```

### settings.py

```
from os import path
PROJECT_ROOT = path.dirname(path.abspath(__file__)) #gets directory settings is in

#-- dynamic content is saved to here --
MEDIA_ROOT = path.join(PROJECT_ROOT,'media')
MEDIA_URL  = '/media/'

#-- static content is saved to here --
STATIC_ROOT = path.join(PROJECT_ROOT,'static-root') # this folder is used to collect static files in production. not used in development
STATIC_URL =  "/static/"
ADMIN_MEDIA_URL = STATIC_URL + 'admin/' #admin is now served by staticfiles
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    ('site', path.join(PROJECT_ROOT,'static')), #store site-specific media here.
)

#-- other settings --
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    ...
)
```

### urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings

#your URL patterns

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns() #this servers static files and media files.
    #in case media is not served correctly
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
            'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
        }),
    )
```

Comment: This _almost_ worked for me. I had to change the PROJECT_ROOT+'site-static' to PROJECT_ROOT+'/site-static'.

Comment: How would you include project wide style and images in this setup? I suppose using STATICFILES_DIRS, but how would you refer to these in your templates?

Comment: Ah probably just by using {{ STATIC_URL }} but how would you load the admin static files within CUSTOM admin templates?

Answer (score 1):

Check `STATIC_URL` from settings.py, what is the value ?